# Rails won't bring me to the Reset Password Form, constantly redirecting me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following Michael Hartl's Ruby Tutorial guide and I'm on Lesson 12： Password Reset Form.

My problem is when testing locally, it won't take me to the reset passwords form. I can see in my logs that it TRIES TO, but instead ends up redirecting me to the home page ("/" root). I have no idea why it's doing this as I am following the tutorial. But it works in production! I have the entire GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/wangjess/sample_app) if anyone wants to take a look.

I have verified that my `routes.rb` is correct as I see the password reset URL using `rake rails`. I have also verified that it is *indeed* redirecting me to / as it is in the server logs:

```
Started GET "/password_resets/D7-YG1GP-RNkdVJFp4PwjQ/edit?email=jessica@example.com" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-06-23 13:13:20 -0400
Processing by PasswordResetsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"email"=>"jessica@example.com", "id"=>"D7-YG1GP-RNkdVJFp4PwjQ"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "jessica@example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:45
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/
Filter chain halted as :valid_user rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Looks like the culprit is `valid_user` function, but it looks fine to me. Basically, the user needs to exist in the database, be activated, and authenticated using tokens. Otherwise, you get redirected.

```
# Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
        unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
            @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
    end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `@user` is activated? To check it add `p @user.activated?` as first line inside `valid_user` method, try to reset password again and look at the logs

Comment: I actually resolved this by ignoring it, pushing to production, somehow working in production, and it works locally too... @_@